# Centering Three Div Tags Inside Of A Div

Tags: css, xhtml, layout, html, centering

I have a container div and would like to place three div tags within the center div, I have the XHTML correct, but what I am having trouble in is, well, centering the three divs within the div.

I will now show the code.

**XHTML 1.0 Transitional (HTML)**

> ```
> <div id="container">  
> <div id="header">
> </div>
> <div id="content">
>   <div id="contentbox">
>   </div>
>     <div id="contentbox">
>   </div>
>     <div id="contentbox">
>   </div>
> </div> 
> </div>
> ```

**Cascading Style Sheet (CSS)**

> ```
> #container {
>   width: 900px;
>   height: inherit;
>   margin: 30px auto;
> }
>
> #content {
>   float: center;
>   width: inherit;
>   height: inherit;
>   margin-left: auto;
>   margin-right: auto;
>   position: absolute;
> }
>
> #header {
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   background-image: url(images/logo.png);
>   background-position: center;
>   width: 250px;
>   height: 250px;
> }
>
> #contentbox {
>   margin-left: auto;
>   margin-right: auto;
>   float: left;
>   display: block;
>   width: 250px;
>   height: 250px;
>   background-image: url(images/contentbox.png);
> }
> ```

To see an example of what I am trying to do, please visit http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/hfc/

I want to know how to center those three content boxes within the content div.

Thank you very much,
Aaron Brewer

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique, and there's no such thing as float: center;

Comment: you should use class for for referring common names rather than ids!

Comment: Your example is 404. Please fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this is what you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/65WHf/1/

Note that ID's are supposed to be unique, and there's no such thing as center floating. To center a div, you must ensure it's positioned relativelly to it's container (wich is the default behaviour of most browsers of my knowledge) and make use of the followinf syntax :

```
.something {
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both; // instead of float
}
```

Comment: I also tried this but it would not recognize the contentboxes #h1 styles and apply them. Thank you though.

Comment: We're not gonna build your page for you - haha.  You can apply the subsequent styles, etc..  yoda's suggestion/jsfiddle example should do what you want.  Everything else isn't in your question.

Comment: Yoda, that is what I want. But, the problem I am having is lining them up side to side in the #content div. True North Creative, I appreciate your help and am open to your feedback... But, I am not asking for you to build my page for me, I am asking this question so not only may I resolve the issue, but learn more. I am a web designer is the beginner stage lol.

Comment: @Aaron Brewer, can you make a graphical scheme?

Comment: Just create a second container, inside #container, and put .contentbox inside it, using the code I mentioned (in the second container you have created). I'm assuming that all your .contentbox are, at most, always the same width as a group, or the same width as individuals.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, 
`float: center;`  won't work. There's no such value for the [float property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float).

use this instead for the `#content` css

```
text-align: center;
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">  
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="contentbox"></div>
        <div class="contentbox"></div>
        <div class="contentbox"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.contentbox {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      float: left;
      display: block;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      border: 1px dashed #999;  /* just for visuals */
      margin: 0 10px;  /* just for visuals */
}
```

You definitely want to stay away from IDs as a general practice, do you can use them with javascript (jquery, etc) libraries.  Plus it's cleaner that way.

Comment: I also tried this but it also didn't work. Instead it pushed the three contentboxes to the upper left of the content div, and it didn't apply the #h1 styles noted in the CSS file. Thank you though.